# FreeRTOS, Atmel Studio - Task not being blocked before it receives a binary semaphore

Tags: c, embedded, freertos, atmelstudio

I'm trying to switch to a blocked task after a button press. Basically I want **task_player1** to do nothing until it receives a semaphore from **task_ctrl**. The way I'm giving the semaphore is on a button press. The code is bellow:

```
#define B1 PIO_PB26_IDX

#define TASK_STACK_SIZE (2048/ sizeof(portSTACK_TYPE))

xTaskCreate(task_ctrl, (const signed char * const) "Control", TASK_STACK_SIZE, NULL, 1, NULL);

xTaskCreate(task_player1, (const signed char * const) "Player1", TASK_STACK_SIZE, NULL, 1, NULL);

void task_player1(void *pvParameters)
{
    vSemaphoreCreateBinary(player1_signal);

    while (1)
    {
        if( xSemaphoreTake( player1_signal, portMAX_DELAY ) == pdTRUE )
        {
            printf("Semaphore taken\n");
            ioport_set_pin_level(L1, HIGH);
        }
    }
}

    void task_ctrl(void *pvParameters)
{
    static signed portBASE_TYPE xHigherPriorityTaskWoken;

    bool button1;
    while (1)
    {
        xHigherPriorityTaskWoken = pdFALSE;
        button1 = ioport_get_pin_level(B1);
        printf("TASK_CTRL RUNNING...\n");
        ioport_set_pin_level(L1, LOW);

        if (button1)
        {
            xSemaphoreGiveFromISR(player1_signal, &xHigherPriorityTaskWoken);
            printf("Semaphore given\n");

            vTaskDelay(1);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is **task_player1** is never blocked as it should be by **portMAX_DELAY**. As soon as I upload the code to the microchip the LED lights up while I only want it to light up once I press the button and the semaphore is given. What am I doing wrong here?

Due to Atmel Studio restrictions I'm using FreeRTOS v7.3.

Edit: Updated code

Comment: How was the semaphore created?

Comment: Generally, semaphores are used to protect a shared resource, not used as flags.  Based on your problem description, it seems you are not showing us all of the relevant code.  Please review [MCVE].

Comment: Why, if the semaphore is signaled in task_ctrl() , do you signal it again in task_player1()?

Comment: @jwdonahue it's not unreasonable to use a semaphore for inter-thread comms.  It's not a flag - you cannot wait efficiently on a flag a flag has no count and a simple non-atomic flag is not thread-safe.

Comment: @jwdonahue created the semaphore with vSemaphoreCreateBinary, forgot to include it here. This code snippet includes code from different .c and .h such as main.c.

Comment: @MartinJames When that signal was put in task_player1() I thought it would exit the loop and block the task again i.e. GIVE BACK the semaphore, I've removed it since but I'm struggling to block the task once it's been run once.

Comment: @Tisa posting a unit back there wil ensure that, once the first unit is posted from task_ctrl(), task_player1)_ will loop forever, continually signaling/postng and setting the pin high -  task_ctrl() will have lost control forever.

Comment: @MartinJames Yeah, I've removed it. It did exactly what you said it would do, but at this point I'm just throwing rocks at it and hoping it works.

The way I understand it, once it has performed the task of setting the LED pin high, it should block that part of the task from running and since there's nothing else in the task to do it won't do anything.

I've updated the code a bit, and I'll edit my question to show it, right now I'm operating  on a workaround until I come up with something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary semaphores in FreeRTOS are created in a "given" state, ie. with a count of 1. Therefore when task_player1() enters the while loop it will set the pin to high without blocking at the semaphore. You could call xSemaphoreTake() just after the semaphore is created to decrement the semaphore count to 0.

task_ctrl() should not be using xSemaphoreGiveFromIsr(), because it is a task and not an ISR.

Comment: This should work, thanks! A quick question - would xSemaphoreHandle player1_signal = 1; do the same thing? Right now, it's set to 0.

Comment: player1_signal is a semaphore handle, you cannot set it to 1. After the call to vSemaphoreCreateBinary just add a call to xSemaphoreTake on player1_signal. Then fix the control task not to call the ISR version of the function.

Comment: Yeah, it worked and I've fixed the ISR function. Thanks again!